# How to remove bigquery dataset permission via CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, command-line-interface

Want to remove multiple dataset permission by cli (if possible by one go). Is there a way for the same via CLI?

for example,

1. abc@gmail.com roles/bigquery.dataowner to dataset/demo_aa
2. xyzGroupSA@gmail.com role/bigquery.user to dataset/demo_bb

Want to remove the email id permission from the respective dataset via CLI with "bq".

[Went through the ref https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#bq_1 , its having local file reference and its very lengthy. But what about when you having a jump server in production environment and need to perform via running commands.]

Comment: you can use the CLI for each dataset. You can't perform a command for all

Comment: Hi @Debayan, BigQuery does not support using a bq command to update all the permissions in a single command. You need to update the permissions using the json file as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#bq_1). Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate this responsability to CI CD for example.

- Solution 1 :

You can create a project :

```
my-project
------dataset_accesses.json
```

Run your script on `Cloud Shell` on your production project or in a `Docker` image from `gcloud-sdk` image.
Use a service account having the permissions to update `dataset` accesses

run the bq script with bq [update-access-control](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls) :

```bash
bq update --source dataset_accesses.json mydataset
```

dataset_accesses.json :

```json
{
 "access": [
  {
   "role": "READER",
   "specialGroup": "projectReaders"
  },
  {
   "role": "WRITER",
   "specialGroup": "projectWriters"
  },
  {
   "role": "OWNER",
   "specialGroup": "projectOwners"
  },
  {
   "role": "READER",
   "specialGroup": "allAuthenticatedUsers"
  },
  {
   "role": "READER",
   "domain": "domain_name"
  },
  {
   "role": "WRITER",
   "userByEmail": "user_email"
  },
  {
   "role": "WRITER",
   "userByEmail": "service_account_email"
  },
  {
   "role": "READER",
   "groupByEmail": "group_email"
  }
 ],
 ...
}
```

- Solution 2

Use [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_dataset_access) to update the permission on your dataset :

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset_access" "access" {
  dataset_id    = google_bigquery_dataset.dataset.dataset_id
  role          = "OWNER"
  user_by_email = google_service_account.bqowner.email
}
```

With Terraform, it is also easy to pass a list and apply the resource on it :

Json file :

```json
{
    "datasets_members": {
        "dataset_your_group1": {
            "dataset_id" : "your_dataset",
            "member": "group:your_group@loreal.com",
            "role": "bigquery.dataViewer"
        },
        "dataset_your_group2": {
            "dataset_id" : "your_dataset",
            "member": "group:your_group2@loreal.com",
            "role": "bigquery.dataViewer"
        }
     }
}
```

locals.tf :

```
locals {
  datasets_members = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/resource/datasets_members.json"))["datasets_members"]
}
```

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset_access" "accesses" {
  for_each = local.datasets_members
  dataset_id    = each.value["dataset_id"]
  role          = each.value["role"]
  group_by_email = each.value["member"]
}
```

This work also with [google_bigquery_dataset_iam_binding](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_dataset_iam)

Comment: I have checked this process early its very lengthy compared to console.
I am looking for something can be run through CLI using bq cmd..
for  example if i have to remove a dataset using CLI cm "bq rm -f datasetName"

Comment: The first solution I proposed is based on a bq command with bq update